# Upload file is not working using AngularJS on lighttpd server

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, lighttpd

In my current project we are using lighttpd server. Here I am trying to upload the file. I am getting two Response Headers, first is with 301 Status code (Moved Permanently) and second is with 200 (OK).

But when I am checking in the folder I am not able to find any file (I mean no file uploaded).

I have tried both way to upload file as given links below:

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/0mz6ff9o/135/

```
ngFileUpload
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

In both way I am getting the same response.
So here I have some sort of questions:

1) Is file upload is possible using AngularJS only? (No Server Side Script)

2) If possible, Is there any config problem with lighttpd?

Thanks ! 
Need Help...

Answer (score 0):

The server side (or any web server) must be configured to handle POST and PUT requests.  CGI, FastCGI, SCGI scripts can be written, or you can proxy to another backend.  For simple file uploads, lighttpd also provides mod_webdav which you can configure (and protect with mod_auth) to allow you to upload files without having to write any server-side code.
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModWebdav